# How do I play fullscreen?

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-3

When applying the fullscreen setting, the game does not go fullscreen. It will go to the specified resolution, but won't be fullscreen; it'll still be a window. I can change back to windowed mode and that works as a window, but fullscreen is not working after the latest patch.

How can I make this game fullscreen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out having TeamViewer enabled would cause this. Killing the TeamViewer process resolved this issue.

Comment: T.V. installs its own generic video driver to be ran over your normal one in place.  I had a similar issue, removing TV resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

For most Windows applications, you can change to fullscreen by pressing Alt-Enter. However, I only *assume* that this works for Battlefield 3.

Comment: This does the same thing as applying the fullscreen option in the Options menu. The issue still happens either way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to play BF3 windowed fullscreen you need to download a program called ShiftWindow, it makes the game/application fullcsreen but has the same actions as a windowed fullscreen.

Comment: League? This is about BF3.

Comment: Sorry, but the same applies.

Comment: No, the same does not apply - BF3 supports full-screen.